# What's the return value for Dom.XmlNode#removeChild for?

Tags: apex

The [`.removeChild`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_Dom_XmlNode_removeChild) function returns a Boolean value. The documentation doesn't tell us *what* the Boolean value represents. Experimentation seems to always yield a **true** value, no matter what I do:

- Remove a node from its parent.
- Remove a node from a different parent.
- Remove a node from a completely different Dom.Document.
- Remove a node more than once from different types of nodes (e.g. [`.getParent`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_xmlnode.htm#apex_Dom_XmlNode_getParent) returns null).

This return value also doesn't match the behavior of [org.w3c.dom.Node#removeChild](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#removeChild(org.w3c.dom.Node)), so I'm at a loss. The function that removes an attribute from a node, [Dom.XmlNode#removeAttribute][4] also has a Boolean return value, but in this case, it's **true** only if the attribute was removed from the Dom.XmlNode; it returns **false** if the attribute did not exist.

Comment: The observation is correct! it always return True no matter what and it never takes null as parameter (gives exception)

Comment: Well , after lot of head scratching I guess true stands for "removed if present" :)